# In C what is the difference between null character and a new line character?

Tags: c

What's the conceptual difference and similarity between <strike>NULL</strike> a null character and a newline character
i.e between '\0' and '\n'
Can you explain their relevance for both integer and character data type variables and arrays?

For reference here is an example
snippets of a program to read and write a 2d char array

***PROGRAM CODE 1:***

```
int main()
{
    char sort(),stuname(),swap(),(*p)(),(*q)();
    int n;
    p=stuname;
    q=swap;
    printf("Let the number of students in the class be \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    sort(p,q,n);
    return 0;
}

char sort(p1,q1,n1)
char (*p1)(),(*q1)();
int n1;
{
    (*p1)(n1);
    (*q1)();
}

char stuname(int nos)  // number of students
{
    char name[nos][256];
    int i,j;
    printf("Reading names of %d  students started--->\n\n",nos);
    name[0][0]='k'; //initialising as non NULL charecter
    for(i=0;i<nos;i++)  // nos=number of students
    {
        printf("Give name of student %d\n",i);
        for(j=0;j<256;j++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&name[i][j]);
            if(name[i][j]=='\n')
            {
                name[i][j]='\0';
                j=257;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nWriting student names:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<nos;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<256&&name[i][j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            printf("%c",name[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

char swap()
{
    printf("Will swap shortly after getting clarity on scanf and %c");
}
```

The above code is working whell whereas the same logic given with slight difference is not giving appropriate output. Here's the code

***PROGRAM CODE 2:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char sort(),stuname(),swap(),(*p)(),(*q)();
    int n;
    p=stuname;
    q=swap;
    printf("Let the number of students in the class be \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    sort(p,q,n);
    return 0;
}

char sort(p1,q1,n1)
char (*p1)(),(*q1)();
int n1;
{
    (*p1)(n1);
    (*q1)();
}

char stuname(int nos)  // number of students
{
    char name[nos][256];
    int i,j;
    printf("Reading names of %d  students started--->\n\n",nos);
    name[0][0]='k'; //initialising as non NULL charecter
    for(i=0;i<nos;i++)  // nos=number of students
    {
        printf("Give name of student %d\n",i);
        ***for(j=0;j<256&&name[i][j]!='\0';j++)***
        {
            scanf("%c",&name[i][j]);

            /*if(name[i][j]=='\n')
            {
                name[i][j]='\0';
                j=257;
            }*/

        }
    }
    printf("\n\nWriting student names:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<nos;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<256&&name[i][j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            printf("%c",name[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

char swap()
{
    printf("Will swap shortly after getting clarity on scanf and %c");
}
```

Here one more instance of same program not giving proper output given below

***PROGRAM CODE 3:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char sort(),stuname(),swap(),(*p)(),(*q)();
    int n;
    p=stuname;
    q=swap;
    printf("Let the number of students in the class be \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    sort(p,q,n);
    return 0;
}

char sort(p1,q1,n1)
char (*p1)(),(*q1)();
int n1;
{
    (*p1)(n1);
    (*q1)();
}

char stuname(int nos)  // number of students
{
    char name[nos][256];
    int i,j;
    printf("Reading names of %d  students started--->\n\n",nos);
    name[0][0]='k'; //initialising as non NULL charecter
    for(i=0;i<nos;i++)  // nos=number of students
    {
        printf("Give name of student %d\n",i);
        ***for(j=0;j<256&&name[i][j]!='\n';j++)***
        {
            scanf("%c",&name[i][j]);
            /*if(name[i][j]=='\n')
            {
                name[i][j]='\0';
                j=257;
            }*/
        }
        name[i][i]='\0';
    }
    printf("\n\nWriting student names:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<nos;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<256&&name[i][j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            printf("%c",name[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

char swap()
{
    printf("Will swap shortly after getting clarity on scanf and %c");
}
```

Why are program code 2 and program code 3 not working as expected as that of the code 1?

Comment: why are you still using KNR C?

Comment: @PrototypeStark The book or the language?  What's wrong with either?

Comment: Why use an old NON-STANDARD language? when there are standard compilers and standards set for the language? Nothing wrong, just bad practise

Comment: @RobertHarvey "K&R C" Has been deprecated for over 23 years, we have C11 for a reason. K&R the book is relatively outdated(Only covers C89, not C99 or C11) with various errata and arguably style issues. In 2012 we have better books available, although I still consider K&R to be a great book, or at least I love the terse style.

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant; it should not be used to refer to the null *character* `'\0'`.

Comment: For the sake of my bleeding eyeballs, *please* indent your code. (I've fixed it for you.)

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain the issue with your old-style function definitions. BTW @zxcdw: "K&R C" refers to the language described by the *first* edition of the book, published in 1978 before the introduction of prototypes. The second edition covers then 1989/1990 standard, and it does use prototypes. If you use K&R2, you'll miss out on some newer features, but you can still write reasonably good modern code.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed, hence why I said "K&R C has bee deprecated for over 23 years", hinting that C89/C90 replaced it when the second edition of the book became available along with the ANSI standard. Up until then "K&R C" was all that was available for the most part. I'd personally advocate "C Programming: A Modern Approach" by K. N. King over K&R, it's more approachable and goes over the language(C99 actually) with more detail(as in examples and recap) while avoiding the errata and style issues. K&R is good(I've read it 3 times myself, and still love it) but we've got better books by now.

Comment: @zxcdw: Just clearing up any possible confusion between "K&R C" (the language described by the 1st edition) and second edition of the book, covering C89, which you mentioned in the next sentence. I'm sure you knew the difference, but others might not.

Answer (score 11):

The null character `'\0'` and the newline character `'\n'` are two different character values, just as `'x'` and `'y'` are two different character values.

The null character, whose value is 0, is used to mark the end of a *string*, which is defined by the C standard as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." For example, the `strlen()` function, which returns the length of a string, works by scanning through the sequence of characters until it finds the terminating null character.

The newline character, `'\n'`, is used to denote the end of a line in a text file. *Strings* exist in memory while your program is running, and *lines* exist in a text file external to your program. You can read the contents of a line (in a text file) into a string (in memory); depending on how you read it, the resulting string may or may not include the terminating `'\n'`.  Null characters do not normally occur in text files.

Note carefully that `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a *null pointer constant*. Other than the fact that both a null pointer and a null character can be expressed as `0`, they have very little to do with each other. Please do not use the term `NULL` to refer to the null character.

One minor thing: in C, a character constant such as `'x'`, `'\0'`, or `'\n'` is actually of type `int`, not of type `char`. (C++ differs in this.) But they're almost always used to denote values of type `char`. For example, this:

```
char c;
...
c = '\0';
```

will store a null character value in `c`, the `int` value is implicitly converted from `int` to `char`. In most cases, you don't have to worry about this.

`char` and `int` are both integer types, and you can freely convert between them. The reasons for character constants being of type `int` are historical.

Also, I see you're using old-style (K&R) function definitions. Way back in 1989, the ANSI standard added a new way to define functions using *prototypes* (you actually use some in your code) -- and there have been two new versions of the C standard since then. Old-style function definitions are obsolescent, and should be avoided. This:

```
int func(x, y)
int x;
char *y;
{
    /* ... */
}
```

is an old-style definition. This:

```
int func(int x, char *y)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

is a definition that uses a prototype, and it's preferred. For one thing, it lets the compiler check that a call passes the correct number and types of arguments.

You'll probably have more questions after this. I strongly suggest you take a look at the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); it will probably answer most of them.

Comment: One thing to note is the null terminator always follows a newline character in the string, even though the newline character "does stuff" after the string.

Comment: @LaurieStearn: I'm not sure what that means, but I think it's wrong. A string needn't contain a newline character at all -- and if it does, the `'\n'` is just as much a part of the string (not "after the string") as any other character.

Comment: Yes, *if* a string contains a newline char. The comment was on the general nature of the question itself, not the code as such. Probably for another question, but can you confirm that writing a newline after a null terminator in a binary stream with *fputwc* actually gets the same behaviour as the newline before the terminator?

Comment: It looks like notepad doesn't parse the L'\n' as a line feed (BOM = BE). But N++ does. Copying the "blank" char over from notepad to N++ gets the LF though.

Comment: @LaurieStearn: In a binary stream, a null character isn't a terminator.

Answer (score 3):

Program #2 and #3 there are syntactical errors.

`'\n'` with Hex value `0x0a` is often used to format text files o/p on screen just for readability.

'\0' with Hex value `0x00` is string delimiter. Although NULL has numeric value `0x0000` it's of type `void*`.

Comment: NO '\n' is only 0x0A and not 0x0d0a

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer constant. `'\0'` is the null character. They're different things. And `'\0'` is *not* of type `void*`; I'm curious where you got the idea that it is. (`'\0'`, or `0`, or `0x00`, can also be used as a null pointer constant, but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: `'\n'` does not necessarily have hex value 0x0a. The standard doesn't specify which specific character is used to represent a newline. It might be ASCII `'0x0d'` or `'0x0a'` -- or it might be something completely different. The C standard (1999) does not mandate ASCII. What the standard does say is that `'\n'` will fit in a byte.

Comment: What does o/p mean?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually both are characters, which means internally they're ascii encoded.

'\0' is integer 0
and '\n' is integer 10.

The programs have errors!

Comment: Why do you assume they're encoded in ASCII? Not all systems use ASCII, and the C standard doesn't require it.

Comment: he isn't using "standard" C. I commented about it before on his question.

Comment: Old-style function definitions are still part of the language, though they've been "obsolescent" since 1989. I see nothing non-standard in his code. And even K&R1 C permitted character sets other than ASCII -- IBM mainframes used EBCDIC. You're unlikely to run into a system where `'\n'` has a value other than 10 (the ASCII/Latin-1/Unicode encoding for LF), but it's important to keep portability in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In the program code 1, if i place '\0' instead of '\n'.
j for loop is not getting delimited.

Here is part of the program code 1 modified:

```
char stuname(int nos)  //nos: number students already read
{
    char name[nos][256];
    int i,j;
    printf("Reading names of %d  students started--->\n\n",nos);
    for(i=0;i<nos;i++)  
    {
        printf("Give name of student %d\n",i);
        ***for(j=0;j<256;j++)***
        {
            scanf("%c",&name[i][j]);

            if(name[i][j]=='\0')    // modified from if(name[i][j]=='\n')
            {

                j=257;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("\n\nWriting student names:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<nos;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<256&&name[i][j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            printf("%c",name[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If we press enter key twice the first enter key will be read as a new line character and
and second enter keyed in will be read as null character while reading char arrays.

So the char array should stop reading as soon as consecutive second enter key is keyed in.
(I mean inner j for loop should get terminated)
But its getting read till 256 keys are keyed in.